# java policy error applet alert

Tags: java, applet, maven, headless

```
[aspectj:compile {execution: default}]
Current policy properties:
        mmc.sess_pe_act.block_unsigned: false
        window.num_max: 5
        jscan.sess_applet_act.sig_trusted: pass
        file.destructive.state: disabled
        jscan.sess_applet_act.block_all: false
        window.num_limited: true
        jscan.sess_applet_act.unsigned: instrument
        mmc.sess_pe_act.action: validate
        jscan.session.daemon_protocol: http
        file.read.state: disabled
        mmc.sess_pe_act.block_invalid: true
        mmc.sess_pe_act.block_blacklisted: false
        net.bind_enable: false
        jscan.session.policyname: TU1DIERlZmF1bHQgUG9saWN5
        mmc.sess_cab_act.block_unsigned: false
        file.nondestructive.state: disabled
        jscan.session.origin_uri: http://commonjar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
        mmc.sess_cab_act.action: allowall
        net.connect_other: false
        jscan.session.user_ipaddr: 10.1.4.91
        jscan.sess_applet_act.sig_invalid: block
        mmc.sess_cab_act.block_invalid: true
        thread.thread_num_max: 8
        jscan.sess_applet_act.sig_blacklisted: block
        net.connect_src: true
        thread.thread_num_limited: true
        jscan.sess_applet_act.stub_out_blocked_applet: true
        mmc.sess_cab_act.block_blacklisted: true
        mmc.sess_pe_act.enforce_for_com_objects_only: true
        jscan.session.user_name: 10.1.4.91
        thread.threadgroup_create: false
        file.write.state: disabled
-->> returning Frame NULL
BaseDialog: owner frame is a java.awt.Frame
```

I'm using maven2.1 on windows7 and get above error. can advice on how to troubleshoot this problem? i'm usinsg jdk1.6. i getting applet alert. how to auto allow all

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the .jar files in your Maven repository opening them with WinRAR or whatever. It will take a while. You don't need to check all of them, just the ones you downloaded most recently. The repository is usually called "m2" or ".m2" and it's usually in your user profile or home directory depending on the OS you're using.

Some of those jars will have a "com" directory inside them. If inside this "com" directory there's also a "trend" directory, congratulations: you're the latest victim of your stupid corporate firewall/proxy/antivirus.

Trend Micro's antivirus is injecting code in the jars downloaded by Maven through your company's proxy. Open the .jars manually and remove the "trend" directories (also remove the com directory if it's empty after that, it could be infected with AIDS or something).

Documentation for this wonderful feature is here:

[Stupid page on Trend Micro's stupid site. F### them.](http://esupport.trendmicro.com/8/IWSx-3x-Some-files-and-folders-are-added-to-the-Jar-files-after-passin.aspx)

I feel your pain.