# Suppressing Applet Alert in a eclipse extension plugin that uses jersey

Tags: eclipse-plugin, applet, jersey, knime, javapolicy

I have written a REST client plugin for KNIME (a software that is based on eclipse). I have used jersey as library.

Everything works fine. However, if I send an client request a APPLET ALERT dialog pops up asking me whether I want to allow, disallow or stop the applet. This dialog get quite annoying, especially if you want to submit multiple requests. 
How do I get rid of it?

All I have found so far, referred to anti-virus software adding stuff to .jar file during download, adjusting the arguments of a maven server and ant builds. However, I have created this plugin on my machine and I am running the target REST server locally (it is based on python).

Ideally I would like to know how to suppress this plugin in my code or plugin settings or via the preferences. If thats not possible I would need a workaround that can also be explained to user outside of our company, since the plugin is going to be published.

The dialog is created by the code line

> client.handle(request)

with client being a jersey Client and request being a jersey ClientRequest.

The console output is

```
   -- PolicyProps uninitialized on access of 'jscan.session.policyname
   -- PolicyProps uninitialized on access of 'jscan.session.origin_uri'
   -- PolicyProps uninitialized on access of 'misc.no_user_interaction'
   -- PolicyProps uninitialized on access of 'misc.prompt_user'
   -- PolicyProps uninitialized on access of 'misc.notify_user'
   -- PolicyProps uninitialized on access of 'misc.max_offense_cnt'
   -- PolicyProps uninitialized on access of 'misc.strict_enforcement'
   -- PolicyProps uninitialized on access of 'jscan.session.origin_uri'
   -- PolicyProps uninitialized on access of 'net.bind_enable'
   -- PolicyProps uninitialized on access of 'net.connect_src'
   -- PolicyProps uninitialized on access of 'net.connect_other'
   -- PolicyProps uninitialized on access of 'net.connect_in_dom_list'
   Msgs: Failed to find localized message for key "instr.action.connect" - using default English form
   Msgs: Failed to find localized message for key "instr.msg.dialog.action_warning_start" - using default English form
   -->> returning Frame NULL
   Msgs: Failed to find localized message for key "instr.dialog.title.applet_alert" - using default English form
   Msgs: Failed to find localized message for key "instr.button.allow" - using default English form
   Msgs: Failed to find localized message for key "instr.button.disallow" - using default English form
   Msgs: Failed to find localized message for key "instr.button.stop_applet" - using default English form
   BaseDialog: owner frame is a java.awt.Frame
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem has been solved. It was a jersey plugin that had code-injections by trend micro (anti-virus software). A new download without has solved the problem.

The problem has been described before here:
[java policy error applet alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667357/java-policy-error-applet-alert)