# PyLucene make fails : [ivy:retrieve] error

Tags: ivy, pylucene

I am following the instructions to install PyLucene, as given in :

https://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/install.html

The problem is when I make, ivy can't retrieve something and it fails.

```
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured
```

Is it possible to download it manually and get it to work, since I have already download everything else.

I have no clue why this is not working, I am behind my university proxy server, and there's nothing I can do about the proxy server.

```
$make
cd lucene-java-4.9.0/lucene; (JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 /usr/bin/ant ivy-availability-check || JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 /usr/bin/ant ivy-bootstrap)
Buildfile: /home/qcsproject/Downloads/pylucene-4.9.0-0/lucene-java-4.9.0/lucene/build.xml

ivy-availability-check:

ivy-fail:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
cd lucene-java-4.9.0/lucene/memory; JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 /usr/bin/ant -Dversion=4.9.0
Buildfile: /home/qcsproject/Downloads/pylucene-4.9.0-0/lucene-java-4.9.0/lucene/memory/build.xml
 [echo] Building memory...

check-queryparser-uptodate:

jar-queryparser:
     [echo] Building queryparser...

check-queries-uptodate:

jar-queries:

check-sandbox-uptodate:

jar-sandbox:
     [echo] Building sandbox...

ivy-availability-check:
     [echo] Building sandbox...

ivy-fail:

ivy-configure:
[ivy:configure] :: Apache Ivy 2.4.0 - 20141213170938 ::   http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:configure] :: loading settings :: file = /home/qcsproject/Downloads/pylucene-4.9.0-0/lucene-java-4.9.0/lucene/ivy-settings.xml

resolve:
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.

[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]  Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy:retrieve]  Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  Host repository.cloudera.com not found. url=http://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy:retrieve]  Host repository.cloudera.com not found. url=http://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  Host repository.cloudera.com not found. url=http://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy:retrieve]  Host repository.cloudera.com not found. url=http://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  Host oss.sonatype.org not found. url=http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy:retrieve]  Host oss.sonatype.org not found. url=http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  Host maven.restlet.org not found. url=http://maven.restlet.org/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy:retrieve]  Host maven.restlet.org not found. url=http://maven.restlet.org/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  Host maven.tmatesoft.com not found. url=http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy:retrieve]  Host maven.tmatesoft.com not found. url=http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  Host uk.maven.org not found. url=http://uk.maven.org/maven2/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy:retrieve]  Host uk.maven.org not found. url=http://uk.maven.org/maven2/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]      module not found: jakarta-regexp#jakarta-regexp;1.4
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== local: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    /home/qcsproject/.ivy2/local/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact jakarta-regexp#jakarta-regexp;1.4!jakarta-regexp.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    /home/qcsproject/.ivy2/local/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jars/jakarta-regexp.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== shared: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    /home/qcsproject/.ivy2/shared/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact jakarta-regexp#jakarta-regexp;1.4!jakarta-regexp.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    /home/qcsproject/.ivy2/shared/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jars/jakarta-regexp.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact jakarta-regexp#jakarta-regexp;1.4!jakarta-regexp.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== cloudera: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact jakarta-regexp#jakarta-regexp;1.4!jakarta-regexp.jar:
 [ivy:retrieve]       http://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== releases.cloudera.com: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy :retrieve]       -- artifact jakarta-regexp#jakarta-regexp;1.4!jakarta-regexp.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== sonatype-releases: tried
[ivy :retrieve]       http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact jakarta-regexp#jakarta-regexp;1.4!jakarta-regexp.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== maven.restlet.org: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://maven.restlet.org/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact jakarta-regexp#jakarta-regexp;1.4!jakarta-regexp.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://maven.restlet.org/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== svnkit-releases: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact jakarta-regexp#jakarta-regexp;1.4!jakarta-regexp.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== working-chinese-mirror: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://uk.maven.org/maven2/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact jakarta-regexp#jakarta-regexp;1.4!jakarta-regexp.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://uk.maven.org/maven2/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      :: jakarta-regexp#jakarta-regexp;1.4: not found
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS

BUILD FAILED
/home/qcsproject/Downloads/pylucene-4.9.0-0/lucene-java-4.9.0/lucene/module-build.xml:118: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/qcsproject/Downloads/pylucene-4.9.0-0/lucene-java-4.9.0/lucene/module-build.xml:550: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/qcsproject/Downloads/pylucene-4.9.0-0/lucene-java-4.9.0/lucene/common-build.xml:388: impossible to resolve dependencies:
resolve failed - see output for details

Total time: 2 minutes 1 second
make: *** [lucene-java-4.9.0/lucene/build/memory/lucene-memory-4.9.0.jar] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this for a long while. I tried a lot of dirty tricks, [like this user](https://superuser.com/q/697800).

Basically, it seems the file ivy-2.3.0.jar that ant needs to build [contains a com/trends directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5313084/5534674) inside the source, as it is downloaded from the maven repo predefined by the config files in the pylucene installer. In my case, those trends classes triggered a lot of java applet alert instances, asking for allowance to connect to ivy...

Additionally you could be missing [to export the ANT_HOME variable](https://superuser.com/a/717815).

So summing up:

Export ANT_HOME, e.g. in OS X:

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.6/libexec
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

Use a cleanly downloaded ivy jar. Download a compressed src [from here](http://www.eu.apache.org/dist//ant/ivy/2.4.0/), extract the jar and "place it" in the required ant lib dir, e.g. by creating a symlink. No problem if the clean version is newer than the required. E.g., again in OS X:

```
ln -s <where you have ivy-2.4.0.jar> ~/.ant/lib/ivy-2.3.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Ant needs to be aware of your proxy settings.

https://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html

Citing from the article:

For Bash

`export ANT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"`

For tcsh/csh:

`setenv ANT_OPTS "-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"`